# tpm2_verifysignature failed when use -d dgst

Tags: hash, tpm

I just tried to verify the signature in TPM with command:

> > tpm2_verifysignature -Q -f ecdsa -s signed.bin -d hashed.bin -c eckey.ctx
> >
> > it was failed with error code 0x2db. the hashed.bin file is raw digest(sha256) data for abc.bin. 
> >     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwY1A.png)

however, if I use the parameter -m and -g rather than -d, the TPM will pass the signature.

> > tpm2_verifysignature -Q -f ecdsa -s signed.bin -m abc.bin -g sha256 -c eckey.ctx

I just do not want to transfer the big message to TPM, please can anyone suggest the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: If `-m` and `-g` work, but `-d` doesn't then you didn't hash the file correctly. Apparently SHA256 needs to be used. It's not clear what you mean by "transfer the big message"?

Answer (score 0):

As @mnistic pointed out, it looks like you failed to hash your file properly. You have two options:

### A) Hash your message on your own

In this case you have to calculate the hash of your data yourself. I consider this the more difficult option.

#### 1) Choose a hash algorithm

You have to choose a hashing algorithm (e.g. SHA256). If you do not use the same hash algorithm for hashing and verifying, your verification will fail.

#### 2) Hash your data

Calculate the hash of your file and write it as raw bytes into a file. This part is tricky. You can use e.g. `sha256sum` but it prints the hash as a hex string in ASCII. What you need is **raw binary data**. To convert it in one command:

```
sha256sum abc.bin | awk '{ print "000000 " $1 }' | xxd -r -c 32 > hashed.bin`
```

#### 3) Signing

Now you sign this hash. Use the same hashing algorithm as above (SHA256 is default if no `-g` is given.

```
tpm2_sign -c eckey.ctx -g sha256 -f plain -s signed -D hashed.bin
```

### B) Let `tpm2-sign` hash your data

This is the easier option, just call sign and pass your data. The tool `tpm2_sign` will do hashing for you.

```
tpm2_sign -c eckey.ctx -g sha256 -s signed.bin -m abc.bin
```

---

### Verification

Now verification just works the other way round. You have to decide if you want `tpm2_verifysignature` to calculate the hash of your message or if you want to do it on your own.

If you do it on your own, calulate the hash as showed above, then call

```
tpm2_verifysignature -c eckey.ctx -g sha256 -D hashed.bin -s signed.bin
```

Alternativly, let `tpm2_verifysignature` calculate the hash.

```
tpm2_verifysignature -c eckey.ctx -g sha256 -m abc.bin -s signed.bin
```

I hope that works. I had no chance to test it on my machine. I assumed you are using tpm2_tools version `3.x`.